# Bluetooth Disconnection Takes Too Long

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, disconnect

I can connect to my bluetooth device and when I want to disconnect it takes about 30 seconds to disconnect and for a few seconds it disconnects and automatically reconnects to the device in the background I don't want this to happen, how can I disconnect it literally?
I dispose service and device and pull to null but that doesn't work

This is Disconnect method :

```
public bool DisConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            IsScannerActiwe = false;
            ButtonPressed = false;
            IsConnected = false;
            
            if (currentSelectedGattCharacteristic != null && currentSelectedService != null)
            {
                currentSelectedGattCharacteristic.Service?.Dispose();
                currentSelectedService?.Dispose();
                currentSelectedGattCharacteristic = null;
                currentSelectedService = null;
                if (bluetoothLeDevice != null)
                {
                    bluetoothLeDevice.Dispose();
                    bluetoothLeDevice = null;
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Exception Handled -> DisConnect: " + ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I dispose the device and the service and pull it to null and the function returns true but it does not break the connection and it is null for a few seconds and the service continues to run in the background automatically

I also tried another function for disconnection

```
public async Task<bool> ClearBluetoothLEDevice()
    {
        if (IsConnected)
        {
            IsScannerActiwe = false;
            ButtonPressed = false;
            IsConnected = false;
            // Need to clear the CCCD from the remote device so we stop receiving notifications
            var result = await currentSelectedGattCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.None);
            if (result != GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentSelectedGattCharacteristic != null)
                {
                    currentSelectedGattCharacteristic.ValueChanged -= CurrentSelectedGattCharacteristic_ValueChanged;
                    IsConnected = false;
                    currentSelectedService.Dispose();
                    currentSelectedGattCharacteristic.Service.Dispose();

                    currentSelectedService?.Dispose(); //added code
                    currentSelectedService = null; //added code
                    bluetoothLeDevice?.Dispose();
                    bluetoothLeDevice = null;
                    currentSelectedGattCharacteristic = null;
                    return true;
                }
                
            }
        }
        return false;
        
    }
```

I literally cannot disconnect from the device

Comment: This is not a C# specific or Bluetooth question. You should check your bluetoothLeDevice implementation.

Comment: GattService and BluetoothLeAdeice implements iClosable interface. You have to call Close() method of that interface to force disconnection. However I'm not sure if it is accessable from c# throught classes you use.